# I want to Implement Back Button but i am not getting how to do it

Tags: ios, swift3, back-button, swrevealviewcontroller

here is the project 
https://github.com/ChinmayDB/TestingSWRevealViewController

With the help of SwRevealViewController i have implemented the navigation drawer to the right . As per the Above Project suppose i am on RedViewController and then i click on barButton it opens the navigationDrawer . Suppose i click on Info(which is working)the user is redirected  to CompanyInfoViewController so i want to add back button on click it will take back user to RedViewController .

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried? You'll get more and better answers If you show what you've tried, and demonstrate that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself. See [Ask]

Comment: i have uploaded the code on GitHub and given the link also @AshleyMills

Comment: Please don't expect people to look through your GitHub repo to figure out your problem. Add code that is relevant to the problem to your question. Help us to help you.

Comment: then i will need to add whole classes code and images of the storyboard separately

Comment: Only post code that's _relevant_ to the issue. Figuring out the minimum amount of code for which your problem is occurring may also help you hone in on the root cause. Remove any funcs / vars that don't relate to the issue at hand. Keep going until you have the bare minimum of code that shows the problem.